# Bash inconsistent behavior between echo / assigning a variable with `set -e` and subshell

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, error-handling

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euxo pipefail

echo $(echo "$THIS_VAR_DOES_NOT_EXIST" | cat)

echo "WTF"
```

Running this script produces:

```
./wtf.sh 
++ cat
./wtf.sh: line 4: THIS_VAR_DOES_NOT_EXIST: unbound variable
+ echo

+ echo WTF
WTF
```

**Why does it run the last command `echo WTF`**? I assume it would terminate the script at line 4 (due to the presence of `set -e`).

Does subshells not automatically inherit the `set -e` option? Or is this some special behaviour?

---

On the other hand if it seems if I don't echo the command and instead output it to a variable it behaves as expected... What?????

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euxo pipefail

echo $(echo "$THIS_VAR_DOES_NOT_EXIST")
echo "this works fine..."

yolo=$(echo "$THIS_VAR_DOES_NOT_EXIST")
echo "this does not"

echo "..."
```

Produces:

```
./wtf.sh: line 4: THIS_VAR_DOES_NOT_EXIST: unbound variable
+ echo

+ echo 'this works fine...'
this works fine...
./wtf.sh: line 7: THIS_VAR_DOES_NOT_EXIST: unbound variable
+ yolo=
```

**Why does this behave differently?**

Comment: What behaviour did you expect? The main shell to exit too when the command substitution runs into an error?

Comment: Yes it does inherit it. The subshell will exit when an undefined variable is used (`set -u`). Exiting a subshell will not exit the main shell though. `echo $(exit); echo foo`, `exit | cat; echo foo`, etc will all go on and echo `foo`.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23026/how-can-i-get-bash-to-exit-on-backtick-failure-in-a-similar-way-to-pipefail https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256873/error-exit-script-from-within-command-substitution also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217605/bash-how-to-propagate-errors-in-process-substitution https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/376114/how-to-detect-an-error-using-process-substitution

Comment: Using a `var=$(...)` intermediate variable assignment is just the way out of this, because the exit status of such an expression will be that of the command substitution `$(...)`. In `echo $(...)` the exit status of the command will be that of `echo`, ie. 0. Try with `a=$(exit 13); echo $?` vs `echo $(exit 13); echo $?`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get bash to exit on backtick failure in a similar way to pipefail?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23026/how-can-i-get-bash-to-exit-on-backtick-failure-in-a-similar-way-to-pipefail)